# How to center a grouped table view both vertically and horizontally on iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I've been looking for a way to center a table view both vertically and horizontally but I can't seem to figure out if this is better done / possible using interface builder alone. If not what method should I override to set this in objective-c itself?

Also will this use the vertical screen size of the device so it actually centers the grouped table view on both legacy iPhone devices and the new iPhone 5?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I also want to know that, now I just set tableview's frame at center and then set superview's background the same as tebleview, a way not better but works.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to get the proper centered frame. Note that the view needs to have proper springs and struts so it resizes when phone calls come in, etc:

```
+ (CGRect)centeredFrameForSize:(CGSize)size inRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = rintf((rect.size.width - size.width)/2) + rect.origin.x;
    frame.origin.y = rintf((rect.size.height - size.height)/2) + rect.origin.y;

//  if(frame.origin.x < 0) frame.origin.x = 0;
//  if(frame.origin.y < 0) frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = size;

    return frame;
}
```

Comment: Any chance you could elaborate on this? Can I do this from inside the "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method? or where should I resize this?

Comment: If you want some view centered in another view, you can use this. You provide the size of the view you want centered, and the bounds of the view you want it centered in. The return is the frame for your view that would get added as a subview of the view whose bounds you passed in.